# Install Ubuntu dual boot on RAID system

Tags: dual-boot, raid

Ok, I'm struggling with this quite a while, the situation is as following:

I want to install Ubuntu 17.10 alongside an existing Windows 7 installation on an older machine. Problem: The system runs an Intel embedded hardware RAID. (Three drives, one in RAID 0 and two in RAID 1, resulting in two virtual drives)

When I boot the PC from boot-able USB with Ubuntu on it, it starts as expected. When I try to start the installation, it says there's not enough space. When I boot the live system, it becomes clear why: Ubuntu doesn't recognize any of the drives, neither virtual nor physical.

How to fix that or work around? Is there no support for in Ubuntu for a hardware RAID based system? If not, how to tell Linux to break the raid? (In the RAID management options, I'm not able to turn it completely off, as far as I could see.)

Comment: convert the Windows 7 installation to AHCI, then install ubuntu.

Comment: Careful with RAID 0. Half of data is on one drive and half on the other. RAID 0 is not really recommended except where you have absolutely no data you want to save. RAID support is in server version. But you need to use Windows to make unallocated space for Ubuntu install. And server install lets you also install desktop of your choice as one of install options.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we can't until Linux catches up with Intel RST.
Switch Raid from RST to AHCI in BIOS and Windows stops booting, but the Linux install can see the drives.
No way around it beyond formatting and installing Windows on an AHCI RAID.